# Invoking 'Hotkey Mode' in IO Gear's GCS632U KVM Switch

Tags: hotkeys, kvm-switch, reset

Awhile ago I changed the switch port key to left control on my IO Gear USB Switch and I'd like to change it back to Scroll Lock.  When I did this, I have some memory of believing that I had found an error in the documentation for the switch regarding how to enter Hotkey Mode.

Per the instructions in the [manual](http://www.iogear.com/support/manual/GCS632U.pdf)**(PDF)**, I'm supposed to be able to enter Hotkey Mode by Holding Scroll Lock for 2 seconds, adding Minus on the keypad for one second, and then release Minus first and within a second release Scroll lock.  Ignoring the strangeness and fragility of this process, I'm looking for confirmation that this indeed works for anyone else.  I can't remember why I thought it was wrong but I clearly remember that I did (I even had a blog post that I was going to write about but it got lost in the sands of time).

As an aside, I'd be interested in seeing if there is any way to force a reset for the switch without entering Hotkey Mode as that would do exactly what I'm trying to do and I wouldn't have to mess with Hotkey Mode.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, I just figured it out.  Hold Num-lock down for at least two seconds; then quickly press and release '-' and release num-lock.  No 1-second waits like the manual says.

(Your question says 'scroll-lock' where I believe it should be 'num-lock'.)

(edit:) actually, on mine I don't have to even wait the two seconds -- just do the sequence quickly and it works.

Caps lock & scroll lights will flash alternately to let you know you're in hotkey mode.

Once in hotkey mode 't' will toggle between use of scroll lock & ctrl double-taps for port switching; 'r', then 'enter', is supposed to reset to factory config.  Either way, hotkey mode is automatically exited.

Thanks for your question -- it inspired me to stop trying to do it exactly the way the manual said!

Comment: Is there anywhere we can meet so I can give you a big hug!?  LOL.  Really, though, thank you so much.  It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

[rw reedy](https://superuser.com/users/40154/rw-reedy)'s post actually helped me.  The no need to hold '-' for 1 second did the trick however there is also another trick.

So to summarize:

1. Hold Num-Lock down for at least 2 seconds.
2. Quickly press and release '-' (no need to wait 1 second).
3. Quickly release Num-Lock (within the same second as step 2).

But... this might not work for you because:

At the bottom of the KVM, there are icons for mouse and keyboard.  If your keyboard/wireless desktop isn't plugged into the USB slot w/ the keyboard, the KVM actually doesn't track any of the hot keys (including CTRL,CTRL).

- Plug your keyboard/desktop combo into the KEYBOARD USB slot (the one on the right when the port is facing you and the lights are up).

I discovered this on my Logitech EX110.  I plugged in a wired keyboard to remap the CTRL,CTRL computer switch toggle, but it would only work on the 2nd wired keyboard and not the Logitech.  When I swapped it over, both the Hotkey mode and the switch toggle both work.

Comment: ahh, I had the keyboard and mouse in the wrong ports

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, all, for the tips. A couple more:

- This procedure worked on my mini keybd that does not have a dedicated numlock key; that is, I was able to enter Hotkey Setting Mode (HSM) by holding fn+numlock then pressing and releasing the minus sign.
- When you're in HSM, the capslock and scroll lock lights on your keyboard (if it has them) will flash in alternation.
- Note that the hotkeys on this KVM work differently than on older 2-port IOGear models. I kept hitting ctrl-ctrl and expecting the KVM to switch focus to the next port, like my old IOGear 2-port KVM did. Nope, its ctrl-ctrl ***ENTER***!
- This extra keystroke enables you to switch directly to Port *N* by typing that number before hitting Enter. E.g if you are on Port 1 and want to go to Port 4, you don't have to type **Ctrl-Ctrl Enter** three times. just type **ctrl ctrl 4 enter**.

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify a pair of USB extension cables with a switch to alternate the +v, connect the -v, and disregard the data. I did this to switch between my HTPC and my 360 and it works great. You can use relay and remote setup if you want to get fancy.